# Socket -io client is not connecting to node-js socket io

Tags: node.js, angular, sockets, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to implement socket-io-client in ionic capacitor (angular based app), but unable to connect the client to server.

Here is my socket-services which I am using in-app module.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
import {environment} from '../environments/environment'

  @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
   



    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
    import {environment} from '../environments/environment'

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class SocketioService {
      socket:any;
      constructor() { 
        this.socket = io('http://localhost:5000',{ transports : ['websocket'] });
        console.log("socket",this.socket)
      }
      setupSocketConnection() {
        console.log("socketio from socket service")
        this.socket = io(environment.SOCKET_ENDPOINT);
        console.log("socket",this.socket)
        this.socket.emit('my message', 'Hello there from Angular.');
        this.socket.on("test",(arg)=>{
          console.log(arg)
        })
      }
    }







<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->
```

this what I get when try to console the socket on client-side

```
socket from app 
     p
     acks: {0: ƒ}
     connected: false
     disconnected: true
     flags: {}
     ids: 1
     io: p {nsps: {…}, subs: Array(3), opts: {…}, _reconnection: true, _reconnectionAttempts: Infinity, …}
     json: p {io: p, nsp: "/", json: p, ids: 1, acks: {…}, …}
     nsp: "/"
     receiveBuffer: []
     sendBuffer: [{…}]
     subs: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
     _callbacks: {$connecting: Array(1), $connect: Array(1), $connection: Array(1)}
     __proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [ngx-socket-io Library](http://npmjs.com/package/ngx-socket-io) for the client, instead of using the `socket.io-client` library.

inside your `app.module.ts`

import like:

```
import { SocketIoModule, SocketIoConfig } from 'ngx-socket-io';
const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: 'http://localhost:8081', options: {} };

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
      ...
    SocketIoModule.forRoot(config),
    ...
  ],
  ..
})
```

Comment: GET http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NfdlPSq net::ERR_FAILED

i am getting this error

Comment: did you run `npm i ngx-socket-io`?  check documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-socket-io